# Multiple Unrelated Entities in one Core Data Model

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I want to have the equivalent of two completely unrelated tables in my database, and for this I have defined two different entities in my Core Data model.

Further to this, I have a different ViewController making use of each of these entities and therefore I'm initializing two different fetchedResultsController (one in each ViewController) in this manner:

```
// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" 
    inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

I should note that the MOM is only initialized only once in the AppDelegate based on the XCode template.

It all worked fine when I only had one ViewController and a single entity in the model, however even though I have the 2nd entity defined in the model I cannot get the 2nd ViewController to initialize the fetchedResultsController (again based on the XCode template).  I always get  the following error:

```
2010-02-11 22:02:55.078 JournalTool[3094:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'EventTag''
```

I'm probably missing something basic and doing something really stupid, but any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Are you using the same managed object context for both fetches? (you should be)

Comment: Yes, the managed object model, and the managed object context are both initialized once in the AppDelegate and I'm simply passing that same context through into both ViewControllers, e.g.
    [tagsViewController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

Comment: This might sound silly, but have you reset the simulator (assuming you're not running on the device) or deleted the app from it since adding the second entity to the model?  Maybe it still has the old model.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the App from the device and the simulator, restarted the simulator and performed a full clean project build several times.  I thought that I was just doing something wrong in having two fetchedResultsControllers referencing the one MOM, but the comments here don't seem to suggest that.

Comment: See here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html One thing it says is to make sure the managed object context is not nil (memory address of 0x0, if you're stepping through and hover over the object).  How are you setting managedObjectContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the `managedObjectContext` you pass to your second view controller is actually `nil`. Before calling

```
[tagsViewController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

verify that `self.managedObjectContext` is not `nil`:

```
if(!self.managedObjectContext){
  NSLog(@"invalid managedObjectContext");
  // now get a valid managedObjectContext
  // and pass it to your view controller  
}
```

Comment: The MOC itself is not nill, but that got me thinking about the ordering on my ViewControllers.  I was actually trying to pass the MOC through to a sub-ViewController and therefore it's the second view controller itself which was nil at this point.

Therefore I changed things around so that my sub-view retrieves the MOC from it's parentView in the viewDidLoad method i.e. self.managedObjectContext = parentViewController.managedObjectContext;    

Thanks for the help resolving this, very much appreciated.

Comment: In order to avoid this kind of problems, I always retrieve the managedObjectContext directly from the app delegate, which is always available in whatever view controller I instantiate.

Comment: That's a good idea, it sounds much safer.  In future I'll make sure all my ViewControllers have a reference to the AppDelegate and then I'll retrieve it directly in the viewDidLoad method.  Thanks again.